# don't show data in ag-grid

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid in angular4. I want to show data using API by getting method. My API is ok and also getting data in the console. But I can not able to show data in ag-grid. I do not understand what is the problem here. When I compile my project, there is no error shown. My project runs in the browser and also showing header name but do not show the data which come from API.

my ts file:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {GridOptions} from 'ag-grid';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
selector: 'app-my-grid-application',
templateUrl: './my-grid-application.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./my-grid-application.component.css']
})

export class MyGridApplicationComponent implements OnInit {

public gridOptions: GridOptions;
public columnDefs = [];
public rowData = [];

constructor(public http: Http) {
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
  rowData: [],
  columnDefs: [
    {
      headerName: 'ID',
      field: 'id'
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Name',
      field: 'name'
    }
  ]
}
```

this is GET method of API link

```
ngOnInit() {
const url = 'http://localhost:3000/studentInfo/students';
this.http.get(url).subscribe(
  res => {
    this.gridOptions = res;
  },
  msg => {
    console.error(`Error: ${msg.status} ${msg.statusText}`);
  }
);
}
}
```

this is my HTML file where I define my grid presentation

my html file:

```
  <ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 650px; height: 200px;" class="ag-
  fresh" [gridOptions]="gridOptions"  [columnDefs]="columnDefs 
  [rowData]="rowData">
  </ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: Seems to me you are not filling your **rowData**?  

`private createRowData() {
        var rowData:any[] = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            rowData.push({
                id: RefData[i].id,
                name: RefData[i].name
            });
        }
        this.rowData = rowData;
    }`

Comment: i have solved this problem using :this.http.get(url).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.rowData = res.json();
        // console.log(res.json());
        console.log(this.gridOptions.rowData);
      },

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem in this way.......

```
ngOnInit() {
const url = 'http://localhost:3000/studentInfo/students';
this.http.get(url).subscribe(
  res => {
    this.rowData = res.json();
  },
  msg => {
    console.error(`Error: ${msg.status} ${msg.statusText}`);
  }
);
```

}

and html:

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 650px; height: 200px;" class="ag-fresh"
               [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [rowData]="rowData">
```